# Linear Anosov map with the set of points of the torus of rational coordinates

Tags: dynamical-systems

Given the linear Anosov map $F_L$ of $\mathbb{T}^2$:
$$z\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
    2      & 1 \\
    1       & 1
\end{bmatrix} z \quad\text{mod }1$$
it's already proved that there exists $P\in\mathbb N$ such that $F_L^P|_{M_N}=Id$, where $M_N$ denotes the set of points of the torus whose coordinates are rational with denominator $N\in\mathbb N$.

I want to prove that the minimum of such number is $P(N)$ and we have that $P(N)\leq N^4$. 
My ideas stop at the point where I note that any rational point with common denominator $N$ is a sum of the vectors $(1/N, 0)$ and $(0,1/N)$ with integer coefficients. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: For related questions have a look at this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864115000590

Comment: @JohnB thanks for your comment! It's a pertinent article, indeed. But I couldn't find any reference that deal with the problem mentioned above. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not from my part, but we do find less likely to be an easy question after reading the paper, right? Overall, it should amount to find some residues. It is indeed a good idea to start with prime numbers!